# Entity Framwork Core – Is a “Insert if not exists” possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I’m currently struggling with a simple SQL problem that I don’t seem to be able to fix with “pure” Entity Framework Core 2.2.

How can I check if an entity already exists during the insert without doing the following?

```
var entity = await _repository.Get(message.Id);

if(entity == null)
{
    entity = new Entity ();
    // do something with the entity
    await _repository.AddAsync(entity);
}
else
{
    // do something with the entity
    await _repository.Update(entity);
}

await _repository.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is not safe enough. I'm constantly getting primary key violations. My service runs on multiple instances and I get messages within a short period of time that have the same primary key.

Is there a better and safer way to check if an entity already exists in Entity Framework Core without writing the SQL myself?

Comment: Sorry to ask but did you try [Transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)?

Comment: Do you generate primary key values on your own, instead of Identity or GUID?

Comment: Yes I do because I get the primary key from another service.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently Upsert is not natively supported in EF Core (open GitHub issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4526#issuecomment-366818031)

Open source library that extends EF Core to support this can be found here: https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert

Comment: Nice find (FlexLabs) - seemingly supports MsSql, MySql and Postgres. Note that unfortunately the underlying MsSql MERGE statement still isn't atomic though, as [highlighted here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: @StuartLC - The FlexLabs MsSql support uses `WITH (HOLDLOCK)`: https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert/blob/develop/src/FlexLabs.EntityFrameworkCore.Upsert/Runners/SqlServerUpsertCommandRunner.cs

Comment: You're right - [code link](https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert/blob/develop/src/FlexLabs.EntityFrameworkCore.Upsert/Runners/SqlServerUpsertCommandRunner.cs#L27)

Comment: It is a pity that this is still not implemented but I guess the open source library could help.